# How to save a word file (.docx) after editing it, with syncfusion : SfRichTextBoxAdv

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, syncfusion

Im using syncfusion for winRT, and i have the following control

```
<sf:SfRichTextBoxAdv x:Name="richTextBox" Grid.RowSpan="2" ManipulationMode="All" IsZoomEnabled="True" />
```

and when my page loads i call this function

```
private async Task GetFile()
    {
        IsLoading = true;
        var bytes = await gappService.GetFileAsync(document.GetFullPath());
        IsLoading = false;

        using (var stream = new MemoryStream(bytes))
        {
            await richTextBox.LoadAsync(stream, FormatType.Docx);
        }
    }
```

after that the .docx opens and i can view it and edit it, but i still havent managed to save it.
i see the richTextBox has a .Save and a .SaveAsync functions but i can't get it to work

anyone can help me please?

Answer (score 0):

managed to get it to work with

```
StorageFile storageFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("file.docx",CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
richTextBox.Save(storageFile);
```